# SQLAlchemy Relationship / Hybrid Property to specific instance of One-To-Many

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a hybrid property or a relationship (either works) to pick out a single model from the "Many" side of a One-To-Many relationship.

The accepted answer for [How to set one to many and one to one relationship at same time in Flask-SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217483/how-to-set-one-to-many-and-one-to-one-relationship-at-same-time-in-flask-sqlalch) doesn't work for me, as I need an expression-level construct to use in additional queries.

Relevant model details are as follows:

```
class ItemIdentifierType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(12))
    priority = db.Column(db.Integer)

class ItemIdentifier(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(8), primary_key=True)
    type_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('item_identifier_type.id')
    type = relationship('ItemIdentifierType')

    item_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('item.id'))
    item = db.relationship('Item', back_populates='identifiers')

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(8), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    identifiers = db.relationship('ItemIdentifier', back_populates='instrument', lazy='dynamic')

    @hybrid_property
    def primary_identifier(self):
        return sorted(self.identifiers, key=lambda x: x.type.priority)[0]

    @primary_identifier.expression:
    def primary_identifier(cls):
        primary_identifiers = select([
            ItemIdentifier.item_id,
            ItemIdentifierType.code,
            ItemIdentifier.value
        ]).select_from(join(ItemIdentifier, ItemIdentifierType,
                       ItemIdentifier.type_id == ItemIdentifierType.id))\
          .order_by(ItemIdentifier.item_id,
                    ItemIdentifierType.priority.asc())\
          .distinct(ItemIdentifier.item_id)\
          .alias()

    # <<< psycopg2 throws the error shown below >>>
    return select([ItemIdentifierType.code, ItemIdentifier.value])\
        .select_from(primary_identifiers)\
        .where(primary_identifiers.c.item_id == self.id)
```

Error this throws when attempting to use the sql expression:

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: FROM (SELECT item_identifier_type.code AS code, instru...
             ^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
 [SQL: 'SELECT code AS code, value AS value 
FROM (SELECT item_identifier_type.code AS code, item_identifier.value AS value 
FROM item_identifier_type, item_identifier, (SELECT DISTINCT item_identifier.item_id AS item_id, item_identifier.id AS id 
FROM item_identifier JOIN item_identifier_type ON item_identifier.type_id = item_identifier_type.id ORDER BY item_identifier.item_id, item_identifier_type.priority ASC, item_identifier.id) AS primary_identifiers, item 
WHERE primary_identifiers.item_id = item.id) ORDER BY item.name ASC']
```

The following *query* pulls out what I'm after, no problem:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (item_identifier.item_id)
    item_identifier.item_id, 
    item_identifier_type.code, 
    item_identifier.value
FROM item_identifier 
JOIN item_identifier_type 
     ON item_identifier.type_id = item_identifier_type.id 
ORDER BY 
    item_identifier.item_id, 
    item_identifier_type.priority ASC;
```