# Sqlalchemy One - Many and One-One in one table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got two models: User and Group.

User can be in one group so:

```
class User(db.Model):
    # other fields
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
```

but on the other hand I would also have some info about user who create that specific group:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    # other fields
    users = db.relationship("User", backref='group')
    created_by = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Result is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Can't sort tables for DROP; an unresolvable foreign key dependency exists between tables: group, user.  Please ensure that the ForeignKey and ForeignKeyConstraint objects involved in the cycle have names so that they can be dropped using DROP CONSTRAINT.
```

I tried `use_alter=True`, but it gives me:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Can't emit DROP CONSTRAINT for constraint ForeignKeyConstraint(
```

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly I'd expect you to get an `AmbiguousForeignKeyError` but instead you seem to get a `CircularDependencyError`? According to [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError) this is caused by two scenarios:

> - In a Session flush operation, if two objects are mutually dependent on each other, they can not be inserted or deleted via INSERT or
>     DELETE statements alone; an UPDATE will be needed to post-associate or
>     pre-deassociate one of the foreign key constrained values. The
>     post_update flag described at Rows that point to themselves / Mutually
>     Dependent Rows can resolve this cycle.
> - In a MetaData.sorted_tables
>     operation, two ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint objects mutually
>     refer to each other. Apply the use_alter=True flag to one or both, see
>     Creating/Dropping Foreign Key Constraints via ALTER.

I'm not sure what you're executing that's causing this particular error, but most likely you'll be able to solve it by solving the ambiguous reference.

The ambigious reference is due to SQLAlchemy not being able to figure out how to perform the join when there are multiple references (users and created_by in this case). This can be resolved by specifying how the relationship should join which can be done by either giving the specific foreign key it should use or by explicitly determining the join condition.

You can see these being applied to your example here:

```
class User(Base):
    # Other setup / fields

    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('group.id'))

class Group(Base):
    # Other setup / fields

    created_by_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    created_by = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[created_by_id])
    users = relationship("User", backref="group", primaryjoin=id==User.group_id)
```

Documentation regarding relationship joins: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#configuring-how-relationship-joins

Comment: adding `creation = relation("Group", foreign_keys="Group.created_by_id, back_populates="created_by", uselist=False)` to the User Model enables the bidirectional relation (uselist=False for 1-1 relation)

Comment: defining the foreing_keys values within the relation as well as the primaryjoin solved it for me.... I had another problem that other people may encounter: I wasn't using alembic migrations for my testing db so after amending the error with the above code it was still lagging behind my dev db and resulted in a huge confusion for me (also because I was not deleting the tables after each test run) so that wasted quite a lot of time.